# Convert regex Captures into HashMap in Rust?

Tags: regex, hashmap, rust, regex-group

I have a `Regex` with an unknown number of named groups with unknown names. I want to match a string to that regex, and get a `HashMap<&str, &str>` with the name of the groups as key and the captured strings as value.

How can I do this? Will I have to use `regex.captures(str).iter()` and then somehow map and filter and collect into a map? Or is there some shortcut?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is tricky because the regex can have multiple matches, and each capture can be matched multiple times in a single global match.

Maybe something like this [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e23ca5e53320ba02007c86f0bb3585b7):

```
fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new(r"(?P<y>\d{4})-(?P<m>\d{2})-(?P<d>\d{2})").unwrap();
    let text = "2012-03-14";
    let caps = re.captures(text).unwrap();
    let dict: HashMap<&str, &str> = re
        .capture_names()
        .flatten()
        .filter_map(|n| Some((n, caps.name(n)?.as_str())))
        .collect();
    println!("{:#?}", dict);
}
```

That outputs:

```
{
    "y": "2012",
    "d": "14",
    "m": "03"
}
```

The code is simple once you realize that the capture names are not available from the `Match` itself, but from the parent `Regex`. You have to do the following:

1. Call `capture_names()`, that will be an iterable of `Option<&str>`.
2. `flatten()` the iterable, that will remove the `None` and *unwrap* the `&str` values.
3. `filter_map()` the capture names into a list of tuples *(name, value)* of type `(&str, &str)`. The `filter` is needed to remove captures that are not present (thanks to @Anders).
4. `collect()`! This just works because `HashMap<K, V>` implements the trait  `FromIterator<(K, V)>`, so an iterator of `(&str, &str)` collects into a `HasMap<&str, &str>`.

Comment: This panics if a a named group is missing. It can be fixed by using `filter_map(|n| Some((n, captures.name(n)?.as_str())))` instead of the `map`.

Comment: @Anders: Oh, you are right. I'll fix it as you suggested. Although a more idiomatic solution would be to create a `HasMap<&str, Option<&str>>` by using instead `map(|n| (n, caps.name(n).map(|m| m.as_str())))`

Comment: Good suggestion with the option.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple captures, you can collect them into a list like this:

```
let all: Vec<HashMap<&str, &str>> = re
    .captures_iter("2012-01-12 , 2013-07-11 , 2014-09-14")
    .map(|caps| {
        re.capture_names()
            .map(|o| o.and_then(|n| Some((n, caps.name(n)?.as_str()))))
            .flatten()
            .collect()
    })
    .collect();

println!("{:#?}", all);
```